# Trying to Add a LEFT Sidebar?

Tags: functions, sidebar

I'm running the base 2016 wordpress theme. I have modified it to allow for a left side sidebar. I am able to see the admin side of the sidebar like so:

[image: LOOK AT SLEFT]

I have registered the call in the functions.php page like so:

```
register_sidebar( array(
    'name'          => __( 'sleft', 'twentysixteen' ),
    'id'            => 'sleft',
    'description'   => __( 'Add widgets here to appear in your sidebar.', 'twentysixteen' ),
    'before_widget' => '<section id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
    'after_widget'  => '</section>',
    'before_title'  => '<h2 class="widget-title">',
    'after_title'   => '</h2>',
) );
```

I have then set up an sleft.php file that has the following in it:

```
<?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-left' )  ) : ?>
      <aside id="secondary" class="sidebar widget-area" role="complementary">
          <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-left' ); ?>
      </aside><!-- .sidebar .widget-area -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

At the top of Single.php, Page.php, Search.php, Archive.php, and 404.php I have added the following line like so:

```
 <?php

   /** header to file

   get_header(); ?>

   <?php get_sidebar(sleft); ?>
```

At the bottom of each of those files I have denoted the previous sidebar so that it's called directly and not indirectly, like so:

```
<?php get_sidebar(sidebar-1); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

CSS is standard that came with the package. I made one entry for the sleft call, like so:

```
.sleft {
    margin-bottom: 3.5em;
    padding: 0 7.6923%;
 }
```

What is occurring is that the 2nd sleft sidebar is NOT showing up. The page is being shoved to the right like so:

[image: page pushed to the right]

Here is a screen capture of the issue:

http://bit.ly/WP-SIDEBAR-ISSUE

**How do I fix this problem ?**

Comment: can you show your css?

Comment: @HowardE , css call added above. It's the standard that came with 2016 with one addition.

Comment: Without being able to inspect your actual site, you need to use css to position your sidebar float:left or using position to get it to the left.

Comment: @HowardE I'd be happy to show it to you, but it's local to my machine. I can show you a screen capture --> http://bit.ly/WP-SIDEBAR-ISSUE

Comment: read https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_sidebar/

Comment: @Michael I did. I thought that <?php get_sidebar(sleft); ?> did that.

Comment: read that developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_sidebar again - your line expects a **sidebar-sleft.php** file, and uses the ordinary **sidebar.php** if the specific file is not found.

Comment: You are **missing quotes** around your arguments…

Answer (score 1):

I added after

```
get_header(); ?>
      <aside id="secondary" class="left-sidebar widget-area" role="complementary">
          <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sleft' ); ?>
      </aside><!-- .sidebar .widget-area -->
```

Then

```
aside#secondary {
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 15px;
}
```

Now... if you're going to have both sidebars, you'll have to adjust the

```
@media screen and (min-width: 61.5625em)
body:not(.search-results) article:not(.type-page) .entry-content {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}
```

or something like that.  You can customize the CSS as you need, but this should put you on the right track.

Also.. FWIW, I created a child theme, and added this to it, rather than modifying the twentysixteen theme directly.  This is the recommended method.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid the child theme method. I already have a working site and then to retheme the damned thing, I'm not taking the chance. It's taken me 3 months to get the damned thing the way I want, this is the last touch. I'll give this a try.

Comment: Either way.  Did you try the above?

Comment: Will in about an hour.